# Firebase realtime database GroupBy approach

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime database that acts as the backend to my Android app. The app is to display fixtures for a soccer league. The results are shown in a listview in a fragment.

I have a record structure like so;

- awayTeam
- date
- gameID
- hometeam
- pitch
- time

What I'd like to do is group games by a specific date in chronological order. So if I had 10 games (records), the first 5 played on the 01/04/2018 and the next 5 played on the 01/05/2018, I want to be able to present all of the 01/04/2018 games in there own grouped box and so forth.

In SQL Group By would be easily achieved, but I'm unsure if this is achievable either through a query or if I have to write a recursive function that will build the tree view up and order them by data at the array level.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `group by` operation in Firebase. In fact, you'll find that many operations you're used to from relational databases are missing from Firebase.

What you get in return is a more flexible data model. For example: if you want to group your games by a specific data, you could store them under that specific date as a key:

```
games
  2018-02-28
    game1: { ... }
    game2: { ... }
    game3: { ... }
  2018-03-01
    game4: { ... }
```

Now you can do a simple lookup for all games for a given date.

If you want to group the games by different criteria, you'll probably keep the original list and then create lookup lists (also often called indexes) for each criterium. E.g.

```
gamesByDate
  2018-02-28
    game1: true
    game2: true
    game3: true
  2018-03-01
    game4: true
gamesByTeam
  Team1
    game1: true
    game2: true
  Team2
    game1: true
    game3: true
    game4: true
```

Now you can look up the game IDs either by date or by team, and then look up the properties for each game by that ID.